# Modify style of a html tag inside of a id-element

Tags: javascript, html, css

On my website I have a style like this:

```css
#titlebar a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

and html:

```
<div id="titlebar">
  <nav>
    <a href="#">test</a>
    <a href="#">test</a>
    <a href="#">test</a>
    <a href="#">test</a>
  </nav>
</div>
```

I want to change the style of all the `<a>` tags in the `<div>` with the id `titlebar`. `display` should be changed from `inline-block` to `block`. Is this possible with JavaScript or do I have to search a different way to do this?

https://jsfiddle.net/Ln0a235v/2/

**Complete Context:**

```js
// Using Gurvinder's solution.

menu = false;

function toggleMenu() {
  if (menu) {
    document.getElementById("titlebar").style.maxHeight = "4em";
    document.getElementById("fab").style.top = "calc(4em - 32px)";
    document.querySelectorAll("#titlebar a").forEach(function(el) {
      el.style.display = "inline-block";
    });
  } else {
    document.getElementById("titlebar").style.maxHeight = "500px";
    document.getElementById("fab").style.top = "0px";
    document.querySelectorAll("#titlebar a").forEach(function(el) {
      el.style.display = "block";
    });
  }
  menu = !menu;
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #ffffff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#titlebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #3f51b5;
  min-height: 4em;
  max-height: 4em;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px #757575;
  transition: max-height 0.3s;
}

#titlebar a {
  font-variant: small-caps;
  line-height: 4em;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 16px;
  margin: 0px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: background 0.2s, display 1s;
  outline: none;
}

#titlebar a:hover {
  background: #ff4081;
}

#fab {
  position: fixed;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  z-index: 100;
  /*right: 64px;*/
  right: 3%;
  top: calc(4em - 32px);
  transition: top 0.3s;
}

.main {
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px #757575;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 64px;
}

.content {
  padding: 6em 0;
  margin: 0 10%;
}

hr {
  border: 1px solid #c5cae9;
}

.content img {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 32px;
  margin-bottom: 32px;
  width: 30%;
  min-width: 256px;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px #757575;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div id="titlebar">
  <nav>
    <a onclick="toggleMenu()" href="#">ToggleMenu</a>
    <a href="#">test</a>
    <a href="#">test</a>
    <a href="#">test</a>
  </nav>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
      sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
      rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
      At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore
      eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh
      euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate
      velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis
      eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer
    </p>
    <hr/>
    <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
      sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
      rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
      At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore
      eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh
      euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate
      velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis
      eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is 2017. everything is possible with JavaScript!
well.. almost

Comment: It's definitely possible with Javascript, but there's just a lot of resources out there you can find just by doing a little more research. Check out W3Schools

Comment: @Dumisani W3Schools is not that good. Please advice either MDN or WebPlatformDocs.

Comment: So are you asking us to write code for you? Can't do that. What have you tried? You need to show that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: I am really looking forward for your comments on my answer. Not sure why people are preferring the "hard" way of looping through the elements, making it harder. Just simply, add another clean CSS class, which is really meant for display purposes! So keep the JavaScript for interaction and CSS for display purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with JavaScript. A **better and unobtrusive way** is to use a combination of both JavaScript and CSS:

```js
setTimeout(function () {
  // See from here:
  document.getElementById("titlebar").classList.add("block");
}, 1000);
```

```css
#titlebar a {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ccf;
}
#titlebar.block a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="titlebar">
  <nav>
    <a href="#">test</a>
    <a href="#">test</a>
    <a href="#">test</a>
    <a href="#">test</a>
  </nav>
</div>
```

**Update:** Based on the fiddle by OP, I have applied my solution here:

```js
function toggleMenu() {
  document.getElementById("titlebar").classList.toggle("block");
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #ffffff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#titlebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #3f51b5;
  min-height: 4em;
  max-height: 4em;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px #757575;
  transition: max-height 0.3s;
}

#titlebar a {
  font-variant: small-caps;
  line-height: 4em;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 16px;
  margin: 0px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: background 0.2s, display 1s;
  outline: none;
}

#titlebar a:hover {
  background: #ff4081;
}

#fab {
  position: fixed;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  z-index: 100;
  /*right: 64px;*/
  right: 3%;
  top: calc(4em - 32px);
  transition: top 0.3s;
}

.main {
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px #757575;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 64px;
}

.content {
  padding: 6em 0;
  margin: 0 10%;
}

hr {
  border: 1px solid #c5cae9;
}

.content img {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 32px;
  margin-bottom: 32px;
  width: 30%;
  min-width: 256px;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px #757575;
  padding: 8px;
}

#titlebar.block {
  max-height: none;
}
#titlebar.block a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="titlebar">
  <nav>
    <a onclick="toggleMenu(); return false;" href="#">ToggleMenu</a>
    <a href="#">test</a>
    <a href="#">test</a>
    <a href="#">test</a>
  </nav>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
      sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
      rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
      At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore
      eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh
      euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate
      velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis
      eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer
    </p>
    <hr/>
    <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
      sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
      rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
      At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore
      eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh
      euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate
      velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis
      eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**The changed elements are here:**

```
<a onclick="toggleMenu(); return false;" href="#">ToggleMenu</a>
// Added a return false.
```

CSS Addition

```css
#titlebar.block {
  max-height: none;
}
#titlebar.block a {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: or just use clean css singlehandedly

Comment: @ProEvilz When the style needs to happen based on interaction, **you have to use JavaScript.** Also note that there are 100s of content generators out there, which we cannot edit. So, think of situations like that.

Comment: Not sure why people are preferring the "hard" way of looping through the elements, making it harder. Just simply, add another clean CSS class, which is really meant for display purposes!

Comment: There is no interaction here

Comment: @ProEvilz JavaScript is used for interaction. Let it be a physical interaction or even an environmental change. So, in my example out there, time interacted with my code to change it. Do you accept?

Comment: You misunderstand. In OP's post, there is no interaction stated.

Comment: I now added a jsfiddle with gurvinder372's solution. I should have explained it better, I did not really explain it well. The reason why I want to do this with javascript is because it should be changed when I click on a button and i was searching for a simple solution similiar to editing the style of a id, but with an entire class so that I would not have to edit every single element.

Comment: @ProEvilz I understood perfectly. See OP's fiddle now. **It is a click interaction** by the user.

Comment: @Alexander Do you feel my answer would be right? Coz this is a better way of using my answer. Don't loop through every single element and stress the browser. It's a heavy performance hit.

Comment: Yes, it took me a while to understand it but your answer was what I was looking for! Thanks! https://jsfiddle.net/Ln0a235v/4/

Comment: @Alexander Also, it is always better to add the context. I edited your question to include the context and the JSFiddle that we are referring to at the end. Hope you don't mind. It will be very helpful for newbies using the site like me to get some recognition. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much! I really should have added the jsfiddle right from the beginning.

Comment: @ProEvilz Any commentz? :)

Comment: @Soolie About what?

Answer (score 0):

Plain JS approach

```
document.querySelectorAll( "#titlebar a" ).forEach( function(el){
   el.style.display = "block";
});
```

**Demo**

```js
document.querySelectorAll("#titlebar a").forEach(function(el) {
  el.style.display = "block";
});
```

```css
#titlebar a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="titlebar">
  <nav>
    <a href="#">test</a>
    <a href="#">test</a>
    <a href="#">test</a>
    <a href="#">test</a>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Whats the point in using JS for this? Simple just change the css from inline-block to block?

Comment: @ProEvilz Correct me if I am wrong, didn't OP specifically asked for *Is this possible with JavaScript*?

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over each control and set the display to block

```
var ctrls = document.getElementById("titlebar").getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i = 0; i < ctrls.length; i++)
  ctrls[i].style.display = "block";
```

You can check the fiddle at [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4gz0zhxb/)

Do not know the context, so as you asked giving you the javascript suggestion but it can also be done using css